# Android device not detecting in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I tried to connect my android (Galaxy Grand) device to **eclipse Juno**, but it was not connected. If it's a problem of drivers, it was connecting to my system. I am able to open all my mobile contents(eclipse wont detected). Already I enabled my device's **USB Debugging** option. **Killed adb** also... still issue exists...

Can any one please help me to solve the issue..

Thanks & Regards,

Lokesh

Comment: You probably still need the driver, I have had devices connect to the computer and still needed to install an adb driver

Comment: have you tried adb kill-server/adb start-server?  This sounds like a problem related to your drivers.  You probably need to go to the Samsung website and get their proprietary drivers.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Already I installed adb driver plugin.. Anything required please suggest me

Comment: On some devices you need to go to "Storage->click the overflow menu on top left->and pick a different way to connect

Comment: Have you tried selected "Allow applications from unknown sources" in "Settings"?

Comment: Mobile settings? Where can I find this option in my device?